# How does python handle different python versions for code & imported custom libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6, pythoninterpreter

Say, An app is using python3, but it leverages/installs a custom library (which uses python2.7), will the respective python versions be maintained when their methods are executed?

Ex - a method in the app(using python3) calls the method 'display_result()' of the custom library(written in python2.7), will each method be interpreted & executed with their respective python versions?

The custom library

Comment: No, it won't work. The library will be executed by whichever version of python executes the `import` statement.

Comment: It handles them by not working.